# VBS Freezes When Waiting on Cmd Prompt

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Hard to make a concise title, but basically, I have started an instance of command prompt from VBS to run an exe, everything works great and I verify my feedback with msgboxes of output line. When the command prompt gets to a part that is loading and says Verifying File (XX%), the VBS does not run anymore. It does not crash, it simply never moves on from its line. I even have noticed that if I don't constantly Writeline, it will pause before that. So while I wait, I constantly write a 1. I dont see anywhere it could be in an infinite loop without showing me a messagebox.

Please help.

```
set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set oExec = Shell.exec("cmd.exe")
do while Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        junkChar = oExec.stdOut.Read(1)
        message = message & junkChar
        'errormsg = oExec.stderr.readline
        if asc(junkChar) = 13 and message <> junkChar then
            msgbox message '& len(message)
            message = ""
        end if
        if right(message,1) = ">" and not bool1stCmd then
            'msgbox(message)
            msgbox("Command" & cmdArchive)
            oExec.stdIn.Writeline cmdArchive
            bool1stCmd = True
            'oExec.StdIn.Write VbCrLf
        elseif bool1stCmd then
            if InStr(1,message,"Enter a command>")>0 then
                msgbox "Enter a command!"
            end if
            oExec.stdIn.writeline "1"
        end if
        msgbox "Loop again!"
    Loop
    msgbox "exiting loop"
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the part of the code where "Loading" or "Verifying File" is occurring...? Is there another part not posted?

Comment: That is from the exe that I am running. Since it updates its own output line,I think it is confusing my VBS's read(1).  It loads some info, then gets to Enter a Command, the VBS types 1, then the exe outputs
"Checking the tags for 'CRC' type errors. [48% Done]"